# Switching frequency impact on DC-DC converter output voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter

How much the switching frequency change can impact the output voltage performance of a DC-DC converter?

Given the same output circuitry (switching MOSFETs, transformers, inductors etc.), the controller sees a small change by varying switching frequency, since the controller compensates for this change by adjusting the duty cycle. Thus, the output voltage will stay the same. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No; it is not a homework.

Comment: *small change* being the operative word

Comment: At the least, the size of the "iron core" of any power-carrying transformers or inductors is decided by frequency.  European railways use 16.666 Hz because deadweight is good for traction.   Meanwhile on airplanes, AC power is 400Hz because 50/60Hz cores are too heavy.

Answer (score 3):

Beside impacting the physical dimensions of the converter, increasing the switching frequency offers the ability to push the crossover frequency higher. In theory, the crossover frequency \$f_c\$ is limited to half of the switching frequency \$F_{sw}\$ for a converter like the buck which does not have a right-half-plane zero for instance. Practically speaking, you may end up at a much lower value for noise susceptibility reasons.

Because the inductor current cannot instantaneously react to a sudden output current demand, the output voltage drop of a converter subjected to a current step is dependent upon several parameters brought by the output capacitor \$C_o\$, the equivalent series resistance \$r_C\$ or ESR, the equivalent series inductance or ESL and the capacitance value. If we neglect the ESL contribution and with an infinite bandwidth, the output drop could not be less than \$\Delta I\cdot r_C\$. However, because crossover cannot be infinite, the capacitive contribution can play a role in the transient drop and pushing \$f_c\$ helps cancel its contribution, leaving the ESR drop alone.

It is possible to show that the voltage drop of the closed-loop converter operated in voltage-mode control can be approximated as \$V_p\approx\frac{\Delta I_o}{2\pi f_cC_o}\$. Therefore, if you want to push crossover while still reducing the output capacitance, you have to switch at a faster pace. Keep in mind though that past a certain crossover, the ESR dictates the response. There is a nice study of these phenomena in a 2004 [paper](https://u.dianyuan.com/bbs/u/43/1154015892.pdf) published by the Virginia Tech folks.

Comment: what about the steady-state operation? does an increase in the frequency translates to a change in the output voltage? or does the converter adjusts the on-time to compensate for that? ( again giving the same external circuitry).

Comment: It depends on the control scheme and operation. For instance, if you operate any of the three basic switching cells (buck, buck-boost and boost) in CCM at a fixed switching frequency, then the duty ratio controls the power flow, not the frequency. On the opposite, bring these converters in DCM and the frequency now matters. Finally, there are some controllers which operate in constant on- or off-time and, this time, frequency controls the flows as it indirectly sets the duty ratio.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus, the output voltage will stay the same. Is my assumption correct?

Yes, as long as the swicthing frequency is such that "normal" behavior is not affected then of course, the regulation loop will compensate for the change and its effects and just regulate the output voltage to the desired value **independent** of the switching frequency.

What might change when changing the switching frequency:

- switching losses in the switching devices (usually MOSFETs, diodes)
- ripple rejection by the smoothing capacitor(s)
- Emitted spurious and noise (EMI)
- maximum current through the inductor (if you lower the switching frequency too much), the inductor might saturate.
- impulse response of the converter

Realize that switching converters are usually **designed to work at a specific switching frequency or frequency range**. Normally you should stick with that frequency and not change it.

Comment: What if in the feedback loop the controller (error amplifier) is sampling the voltage across the inductor (which is switching at the same frequency as well) instead of the relatively filtered output voltage as in the case of most converters?

Comment: Why would the voltage across the inductor need to be sampled? Measuring the **current** I can imagine, to prevent overloading. Show me an example of a converter that samples the voltage across the inductor.

Comment: [MAX5974A](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5974A-MAX5974D.pdf) page 26

Comment: *MAX5974A page 26* That's not a simple single inductor DCDC converter. It is much more complex. The inductor is a **transformer**. This is not an example of "sampling across the inductor" as there's more going on. What is going on is unclear as there's no explanation about the purpose of that circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The feedback network, if it’s working properly, servos the voltage back to the set point, regardless of the basic switching frequency. So the frequency can vary (and it does for a constant-on-time regulator) while the output stays the same.

The thing that matters is the net duty cycle, which determines the energy delivered to the load. The packets of energy get smaller at higher frequency, but they’re more… frequent. It’s like getting a ton of rocks vs. a ton of gravel: it’s still a ton either way.

But… let’s discuss buck converters for a bit. There’s a practical limit to buck switching frequency that is determined by two things: minimum high-side on time, and the converter stepping ratio.

For example, if the input voltage is 12V and output 1.2V, that’s a 10:1 stepping ratio. This means that, on average, the switch duty cycle must be 10%. This is true regardless of whether the regulator is PWM or constant-on time.

If the regulator’s minimum high-side on-time is 100ns (common for an integrated-FET type), the required off-time for a 10:1 step will be at least 900ns, limiting the period to no less than 1000ns, that is, to no more than 1MHz.

As a consequence, typical regulators designed for 12V operation making core voltages like 1.0, 0.9, etc. will have practical limits of about 600-800kHz because of the on-time limit. Regulators that work from lower input voltages have more favorable stepping ratios and thus can work at higher frequencies.

In any event, the feedback and compensation network needs to be set up correctly for the chosen switching frequency as well as the regulator type (voltage, current, COT, etc.). I see @VerbalKint has weighed in on this, but know that your takeaway is that this further constrains your choice of switching frequency. Simulate it first.

Answer (score 1):

To a first approximation, in a real buck converter the output voltage is only dependent on the switching duty cycle and the the input voltage. There are small deviations from this because of voltage drop losses across the switches; switching time losses and deadtime losses.

If you raise the switching frequency, the switching time and deadtime losses become larger, thus the duty cycle has to increase. The controller will generally be able to do this (it adjusts duty cycle as needed).

At higher frequencies, the performance of the elements of the circuit has to be improved -- the switching time and slew rates, the bandwidth of the opamps in the controller, the response time of the current sensing circuits etc. Overall, higher switching frequencies can be 'better' -- the inductance and capacitance needed is smaller (so lower cost), but the efficiency is generally lower and this may not be acceptable.